# Sharepoint Workflow - Change Permissions

Tags: workflow, permissions, metadata, inheritance

I am pretty new to Sharepoint Workflows however my first assignment is a bit difficult for me. Basically we are using a 3rd party solution to store emails into a document library (as .msg or .eml) and I have created some required columns in this list. One of these columns is called 'Readers' where a user can enter several users/groups into this field so that only the owner and these users can see this document.

I want to create a sharepoint workflow where I remove any inherited permissions and assign permissions on this document only to the owner and users/groups entered in this 'Readers' field.

Can any one help/teach me how to achieve this please?

Comment: Which Workflow platform you are using( 2013/1010 )?

Comment: I'm using 2013 platform

Comment: ... my answer seems to have been removed by Admins but yeh, when you edit the page, you can set the VIEW of that particular webpart.

Answer (score 0):

2013 wf can´t change permissions

so use `Start SharePoint 2010 list workflow with parameters on this item (Output to Data source)`

Build 2010 wf with logic you need. For that you need to add *Impersonation Step* into it.

But not sure if you can put more groups via current item field into this `Add Read to item in Current Item`

And yes you have to stop inheriting for that list.